# Mocking a service in single test spec and call it globally for all test specs Angular unit test case

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have included cookieservice for login functionality but when executing the unit test cases it is showing error message **No provider for cookieservice** for every test specs. Is there an option to mock cookieservice globally so that it calls in every test specs. Please help me out

```
import { CookieService } from '@alfresco/adf-core';

mockService( CookieService, {
            getItem: () => '',
            setItem: () => {},           
        })
```

Comment: Will you explain it more with your code so I can understand your actual problem in code.

Comment: If I login to my website in any browser and open the new tab execute the same URL it should be automatically login without asking login credentials so I am using CookieService for login functionality. When I execute the test cases by command ng test it is  asked to adding cookieservice for all the other test specs

Answer (score 0):

A unit test spec executed is independent of other specs. Hence we need to inject all the dependencies individually for all specs. Again each Unit Test executed should be independent and should run in isolation.They should not impact or should be impacted by other test cases.
Now coming to your question how to create a global mock that can be injected for every module that we initialize within test bed, would not be a great idea as it might not work since every service that you test might not have the same number of dependencies. Instead what I do or recommend is following:

1. Create a mock object (you can create a class as well) that is exported via file:

```
    // mocks.ts This can reside at some shared location
    export const CookieServiceMock = {
        setCookie(): void => undefined
    }
```

2. Inject the TestBed with the new mock

```
import { CookieServiceMock } from 'mocks.ts' 
describe('ServiceToTest', () => {
  let serviceToTest: ServiceToTest; // Replace with your service
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
         ServiceToTest
         // Below line will replace your service with mock and
         // needs to be done at all places where cookieService is dependency.
         
         {provide: CookieService, useValue:  CookieServiceMock } 
         //useClass if CookieService mock is a class
         //This way you don't need inject the dependencies explicitly for injected 
         //services.
      ],
      imports: []
    });
     // Get the instance of service to test
     serviceToTest = TestBed.get(ServiceToTest);  
     
     // This will now return the instance of mock i.e. CookieServiceMock object
     cookieService = TestBed.get(CookieService);  
 });

 it('Service to test',()=>{
   // Now you can access all the methods to test within your target service 
   // and also your methods that you want to Spy from your mock.
 })
});
```

Another approach is in case you want to keep some configurations common for all the test module would be to:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule(
// Extract out this Object. 
// But this might not work in most cases since every service or 
// component to test have a different dependencies.
{ 
      providers: [],
      imports: []
    });
```